# Generate inserts in oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

If i can generate DDL using dbms_metadata.ddl_get (..) to get all the data about creation a type, how could I generate insert statements? Using code/commands, because I need to put them into a file, then import them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dump Oracle table(s) data to INSERT statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034782/dump-oracle-tables-data-to-insert-statements)

Answer (score 11):

As you say, 'in SQL Developer' - so here is a SQL Developer-specific solution:

Run a query in the SQL Worksheet to get the data you want.

Include the following hint, this will tell SQL Developer when it's executed as a script, to auto-format the results as INSERT statements.

```
select /*insert*/ * from hr.employees;
```

execute as script (f5)

```
REM INSERTING into HR.EMPLOYEES
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',to_date('17-JUN-87','DD-MON-RR'),'AD_PRES',24000,null,null,90);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (101,'Neena','Kochhar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',to_date('21-SEP-89','DD-MON-RR'),'AD_VP',17000,null,100,90);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (102,'Lex','De Haan','LDEHAAN','515.123.4569',to_date('13-JAN-93','DD-MON-RR'),'AD_VP',17000,null,100,90);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (103,'Alexander','Hunold','AHUNOLD','590.423.4567',to_date('03-JAN-90','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',9000,null,102,60);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (104,'Bruce','Ernst','BERNST','590.423.4568',to_date('21-MAY-91','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',6000,null,103,60);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (105,'David','Austin','DAUSTIN','590.423.4569',to_date('25-JUN-97','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',4800,null,103,60);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (106,'Valli','Pataballa','VPATABAL','590.423.4560',to_date('05-FEB-98','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',4800,null,103,60);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (107,'Diana','Lorentz','DLORENTZ','590.423.5567',to_date('07-FEB-99','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',4200,null,103,60);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (108,'Nancy','Greenberg','NGREENBE','515.124.4569',to_date('17-AUG-94','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_MGR',12000,null,101,100);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (109,'Daniel','Faviet','DFAVIET','515.124.4169',to_date('16-AUG-94','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',9000,null,108,100);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (110,'John','Chen','JCHEN','515.124.4269',to_date('28-SEP-97','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',8200,null,108,100);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (111,'Ismael','Sciarra','ISCIARRA','515.124.4369',to_date('30-SEP-97','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',7700,null,108,100);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (112,'Jose Manuel','Urman','JMURMAN','515.124.4469',to_date('07-MAR-98','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',7800,null,108,100);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (113,'Luis','Popp','LPOPP','515.124.4567',to_date('07-DEC-99','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',6900,0.5,108,100);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (114,'Den','Raphaely','DRAPHEAL','515.127.4561',to_date('07-DEC-94','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_MAN',11000,null,100,30);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (115,'Alexander','Khoo','AKHOO','515.127.4562',to_date('18-MAY-95','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',3100,null,114,30);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (116,'Shelli','Baida','SBAIDA','515.127.4563',to_date('24-DEC-97','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2900,null,114,30);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (117,'Sigal','Tobias','STOBIAS','515.127.4564',to_date('24-JUL-97','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2800,null,114,30);
Insert into HR.EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (118,'Guy','Himuro','GHIMURO','515.127.4565',to_date('15-NOV-98','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2600,null,114,30);
...

107 rows selected.
```

You can also use the SET command to turn on the formatter for all query/script results.

```
SET SQLFORMAT insert -- csv, delimited, xml, json, html are also available
```

This also works in Oracle SQLcl, our new and modern command line interface for Oracle Database.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the SELECT statement that shows the data you want to INSERT.
In the result set, right-click and select 'Export ...'.
Select 'insert' as format

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Mark's answer.. you can also just navigate to your table from under connections, right click on the name and then generate the insert script using the export option.